# set scrollable wallpaper across homescreen

Tags: android, wallpaper, android-screen-support, android-wallpaper

I want to set **scrollable wallpaper** on homescreen but my wallpaper gets **center crop** automatically.
The images i am using are in ratio "3:2/ 16:9" so i want them to get spread uniformly on **multiple pages** of homescreen.

I am currently using:

```
wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
wallPaperBitmap = BitmapFactory.
                        decodeStream(url);

wallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallPaperBitmap);
```

`

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Got the help from androidhive.com

```
//get screen height
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenHeight = size.y;


 wallPaperBitmap= ... //your bitmap resource

//adjust the aspect ratio of the Image
//this is the main part
int width = wallPaperBitmap.getWidth();
            width = (width * screenHeight) / wallPaperBitmap.getHeight();
//set the wallpaper
//this may not be the most efficent way but it works
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(wallPaperBitmap, width, height, true));
```